# webapp2 request handler and byte arrays

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am writing a python service with webapp2 and want to get a byte-array from a client POST request and save it to a file.

Whenever I am trying to get the data field that containes the byte array from the request object I get an exception saying:

```
 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

my post() code:

```
def post(self):
    file_data = self.request.get('file_data')
```

Is there another method I should use to read the field because it's not a string?

Comment: `0xff` looks like the first byte of a UTF-16 little endian byte order marker (0xFF 0xFe). Is there any chance that the data is utf-16 instead of utf-8? How is the data being sumbitted?

Comment: It is sent from an iPhone device using afnetworking lib

Comment: Can you dump the form data out somewhere so that you can get a look at the raw data?

Comment: You can always use self.request.body to get the raw request. Morre here: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes

Comment: @voscausa, please flesh this out into an answer (just a small Python example added to the link will suffice) so the OP can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [self.request.body](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes) to get the raw request (a byte string)

utf-8 json string request example:

```
def post(self):

    binary_body = self.request.body                  # get the binary request
    utf8_json_string = binary_body.decode('utf-8')
    json_object = json.loads(utf8_json_string)
```

More on unicode [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python).